# IIS handler for phtml files

Tags: php, html, iis

I did not find many results online for this one, surprisingly.
I have a local PHP project containing different types of files.
PHTML files do not seem to be parsed correctly by IIS.
The type phtml is not listed in the module mappings in IIS.
I tried to add *.phtml with php-cgi.exe and then php.exe to the handlers/module mappings, to no avail.

Anything I am missing there?
Also, isn't that supposed to be automatically done when installing PHP?
This is the first time I have this problem, but it seems obvious I did something differently this time :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was obviously between the chair and the monitor.
I forgot to set `short_open_tag = On`, in the php.ini file.
The short tags were used mostly in our phtml files, leading me to think it was a filetype issue.